# Text overflowing from div

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm making a website with a dropdown menu, for which I'm using ul. 
I have a div which contains this ul. However, the text is not being displayed inside the div; it is below it.

```
 ________________
|________________|  //This is the div
    Categories      //This is the text of the ul inside the div.
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li id="top"><a href="index.html">Categories</a>
                <span></span>
                <ul class="dropdown-box">
                    <li><a href="#">LI1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LI2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LI3</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.nav{
    float:right;
    margin-right: 5%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#top a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 25px;
}

ul li{
    list-style:none;
}

.dropdown{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.dropdown li .dropdown-box{
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:none;
    height:0;
    padding:0;
    width: 100%;
}

.dropdown li .dropdown a{
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 20px;
} 

.dropdown li:hover .dropdown-box, .dropdown li:active .dropdown-box {
    display:block;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    animation: box 2s ease;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

You can see the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zbaq6546/).

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/t86tr721/

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post a screenshot, but my browser doesn't seem to display it properly. I checked in both Google Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Try setting the padding on your .dropdown ul element to 0.

Comment: It made no difference.

Comment: how about removing height:0; from .dropdown-box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header font-size makes it below the div. Remove the font-size: 56px from header class, and add font-size: 56px into #site_header

CSS:

```
.header{
    background-color: #31c68b;
    font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    /* font-size: 56px; */
}

#site_header{
    margin-left: 5%;
    height: 56px;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 56px;
}
```

Comment: No I'm using Chrome. I also checked this in Firefox. Maybe it has something to do with my screen size?

Comment: I've tried in different resolution， all of them worked right. I think maybe there is other css code which overwrites .dropdown class.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zbaq6546/

Here is the jsfiddle of the entire CSS. I can't figure out what is causing this.

Comment: I figured it out. The header font-size makes it below the div. Remove the font-size: 56px from header class, and add font-size: 56px into #site_header                                                                                         header{
    background-color: #31c68b;
    font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    /*font-size: 56px;*/
}

#site_header{
    margin-left: 5%;
    height: 56px;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 56px;
}

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. 
I thought the property you specify separately is the one taken into account.
@scorpion , do answer this sepaately so I can accept it.

Comment: My English is poor, so I don't understand what you mean exactly. Do I need to add another answer so you can accept it. @LM10